# C# Events - Raising specific event based on string

Tags: c#, events

I am writing a class to process events coming in on a single event with a string value and map them to and raise specific events based on the string value.

It all works fine with a switch such as

```
SpecificHandler handler = null;
SpecificArgs args = new SpecificArgs(Id, Name);   
switch (IncomingEventName)
{ 
    case "EVENT1":
        handler = Event1Handler;
        break;
    case "EVENT2":
        handler = Event2Handler;
        break;
    ... etc
}
if (handler != null) handler(this, args);
```

But the switch list can get far too long so I'd like a way so map the string event to the handler in a data structure (e.g. List of KeyValuePair) so I can just locate the item for the string event and raise the associated event.

Any tips/ideas most welcome.

Thanks

Comment: do you need to raise different events? could you just pass the string as part of the `EventArgs`?

Comment: Daniel - Thanks, I could but the purpose of this intermediate class is to hide the strings to the clients by creating the more meaningful event names.

Answer (score 4):

You can just use a dictionary. However, be careful to not target the delegates but lazy evaluations of them. As a reason, delegates are immutable and thus you would not receive any event handlers, otherwise.

```
private static Dictionary<string, Func<Yourtype, SpecificHandler>> dict = ...
dict.Add("Foo", x => x.FooHappened);
dict.Add("Bar", x => x.BarHappened);
```

and use it like this:

```
Func<SpecificHandler> handlerFunc;
SpecificArgs args = new SpecificArgs(...);
if (dict.TryGetValue(IncomingEventName, out handlerFunc))
{
    SpecificHandler handler = handlerFunc(this);
    if (handler != null) handler(this, args);
}
```

Comment: Like the look of this and have suffered from the immutable nature of delegates in an early attempt. I have tried this ... 

    private static Dictionary<string, Func<object, SpecificArgs>> dict = new Dictionary<string,Func<object,SpecificArgs>>();
 
 ...
 
 dict.Add("EVENT1",  x => x.Event1Handler);

but I get a syntax error when adding to the dictionary of 

Object does not contain a definition for Event1Handler and there is no extension method of Event1Handler which takes an object as its first parameter.

Comment: @GeoffKell I was assuming that you knew the events at compile-time. For that case, I created this placeholder Yourtype so that you can navigate to the events you require. If you can at least do that per event, you can add casts to the funcs in your dictionary. Otherwise, you will need to access the events using reflection.

Comment: Georg - Was a silly mistake on my part - Your original suggestion worked a treat once I fixed my mistake. Thanks very much. Code now look so much cleaner :)

Answer (score -1):

Initialize a dictionary  with event name as key and event handler as value .Then you can easily access the event handler.

//initialize the dictionary

```
     Dictionary<string,EventHandler> dic=new Dictionary<string, EventHandler>();
     dic["EVENT1"] = Event1Handler;
```

and instead of switch case use the below code

```
            if (dic.ContainsKey(IncomingEventName))
            {
                var handler = dic[IncomingEventName];
                if (handler != null) handler(this, args);
            }
```

Comment: I haven't tested it, but as Delegate instances are immutable, you basically hard-wire to the event-handlers that were present when you added the delegates to the dictionary. Given that you may want to do that very early (in the object or even type constructor), your dictionary may be empty.

Comment: Agree with Georg on this. I tried this and when stepping through they were all null